# Finding the Type of Scanning in DICOM header

Tags: dicom

I am a beginner in DICOM and would like to know whether there is a DICOM tag and what it is that can tell me which kind of the scanning an image is. I have to manage normal 2D scanning, 3D scanning and 2D multi-slice scanning from MRI with different methods.

I have found the reference of DICOM, but there are too many information and I am not sure that whether there is a tag do the job.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[How to decide if a DICOM series is a 3D volume or a series of images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529967/how-to-decide-if-a-dicom-series-is-a-3d-volume-or-a-series-of-images/18597180#18597180)

Has some useful information that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I have used the spacing in DICOM header. If the DICOM image is a normal 2D image, it has no spacing. But I is a 2D multi-slice, it has :)

I don't know whether this is correct or not.